# Azure API Management SOAP to REST

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are moving from old SOAP Web Service calls for our customers to call to new Azure Functions/REST API calls.

We would like to be able to use Azure API Management to convert the OLD SOAP messages into REST calls for our customers so that they do not have to rewrite their side and can continue to use the SOAP messages.

I've found little to no documentation on how to make this work.  I've tried fiddling with it using the WSDL from our Old SOAP services and then pointing that to the Azure API but I get nothing but errors.

I don't see a way to get any detailed info.

I understand that I need to use the Liquid Templates to transform the SOAP Message which has about 10 properties and is an array of data into JSON but I've had zero luck figuring that out.

Does anyone have any resources on how to get this to work?

Adding the below example data.

This is what we call the Legacy SOAP Message.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ad="http://ad-c.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ad:ImportItemMovement>
            <ad:authenticationToken>0badec32-81f7-4f88-813f-2dbfb62b4484</ad:authenticationToken>
            <ad:movementArray>
                <ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
                    <ad:OrgUnitNum>52</ad:OrgUnitNum>
                    <ad:MovementDateTime>2020-10-06T09:55:50</ad:MovementDateTime>
                    <ad:RetailSold>5.99</ad:RetailSold>
                    <ad:QtySold>300</ad:QtySold>
                    <ad:ItemNum>123456789</ad:ItemNum>
                    <ad:UpcNum>00021234500000</ad:UpcNum>
                </ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
                <ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
                    <ad:OrgUnitNum>54</ad:OrgUnitNum>
                    <ad:MovementDateTime>2020-10-06T09:55:50</ad:MovementDateTime>
                    <ad:RetailSold>5.99</ad:RetailSold>
                    <ad:QtySold>300</ad:QtySold>
                    <ad:ItemNum>123456789</ad:ItemNum>
                    <ad:UpcNum>00021234500000</ad:UpcNum>
                </ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
            </ad:movementArray>
        </ad:ImportItemMovement>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the CURRENT policy with the help of @DSpirit

```
    <policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <find-and-replace from="ad:" to="" />
        <find-and-replace from="soapenv:" to="" />
        <xml-to-json kind="direct" apply="always" consider-accept-header="true" />
        <trace source="inbound">@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(true))</trace>
            <set-body>@{
                 var body = JObject.Parse(context.Request.Body.As<string>());
                 return body["Envelope"]["Body"]["ImportItemMovement"]["movementArray"]["WSItemMovementInfo"]?.ToString();
                 }</set-body>
                <set-body template="liquid">
                [
                 {% JSONArrayFor item in body %}
                 {
                 "StoreNumber": {{ item.OrgUnitNum }},
                 "BarcodeNumber": "{{ item.UpcNum }}",
                 {% if item.WgtSold %}
                 "Type": "W",
                 "QuantitySold": {{ item.WgtSold }},
                 {% endif %}
                 {% if item.QtySold %} 
                 "Type": "Q",
                 "QuantitySold": {{ item.QtySold }},
                 {% endif %}
                 "TotalRetail": {{ item.RetailSold }},
                 {% if item.onPromotion %}
                 "PromotionType": {{ item.onPromotion }},
                 {% else %}
                 "PromotionType": 0,
                 {% endif %}
                 "SerialNumber": "{{ item.labelSerialNum }}",
                 "MovementDateTime": "{{ item.MovementDateTime }}"
                 }
                 {% endJSONArrayFor %}
                 ]
            </set-body>
        <!-- Here you should forward the request to the function backend instead of returning it -->
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://proxy.freshiq.com/prod/inventory/" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Here is what the Azure REST API is expecting.

```
  [{
      "StoreNumber": 0,
      "BarcodeNumber": "string",
      "Type": "string",
      "QuantitySold": 0.5229864343061676,
      "TotalRetail": 0.2568850594082819,
      "PromotionType": 0,
      "SerialNumber": "string",
      "MovementDateTime": "string"
  },
  {
      "StoreNumber": 0,
      "BarcodeNumber": "string",
      "Type": "string",
      "QuantitySold": 0.5229864343061676,
      "TotalRetail": 0.2568850594082819,
      "PromotionType": 0,
      "SerialNumber": "string",
      "MovementDateTime": "string"
  }]
```

The mapping from SOAP XML to REST JSON is:

```
OrgUnitNum = StoreNumber
UpcNum = BarcodeNumber
If WgtSold exits Then Type = "W"
If QtySold exist then Type = "Q"
WgtSold if exists or QtySold if exists = QuantitySold
RetailSold = TotalRetail 
onPromotion = PromotionType 
labelSerialNum = SerialNumber
MovementDateTime = MovementDateTime
```

With the above it does seem to work with 1 exception the JSON that is produced the first record of the 2 has the names of the SOAP fields not the JSON ones but the second record in the "FOR" loop is correct.  I'm not sure what would cause that.

Comment: Can you please provide an example: Soap data and your current liquid template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've scrapcoded a policy which returns the desired output I guess.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <find-and-replace from="ad:" to="" />
        <find-and-replace from="soapenv:" to="" />
        <xml-to-json kind="direct" apply="always" consider-accept-header="true" />
        <trace source="inbound">@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(true))</trace>
        <set-body>@{
                var body = JObject.Parse(context.Request.Body.As<string>());
                return body["Envelope"]["Body"]["ImportItemMovement"]["movementArray"]["WSItemMovementInfo"]?.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            {
                "StoreNumber": {{ body.OrgUnitNum }},
                "BarcodeNumber": "{{ body.UpcNum  }}",
                {% if body.WgtSold %}
                "Type": "W",
                "QuantitySold": {{ body.WgtSold }},
                {% endif %}
                {% if body.QtySold  %}                
                "Type": "Q",
                "QuantitySold": {{ body.QtySold }},
                {% endif %}
                "TotalRetail": {{ body.RetailSold }},
                "PromotionType": {{ body.onPromotion }},
                "SerialNumber": "{{ body.labelSerialNum }}",
                "MovementDateTime": "{{ body.MovementDateTime }}"
            }</set-body>
        <!-- Here you should forward the request to the function backend instead of returning it -->
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="Ok" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body template="none">@(context.Request.Body.As<string>())</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

For this input:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ad="http://company.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ad:ImportItemMovement>
         <ad:authenticationToken>0badec32-81f7-4f88-813f-8hgty27b4484</ad:authenticationToken>
         <ad:movementArray>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
               <ad:OrgUnitNum>52</ad:OrgUnitNum>
               <ad:MovementDateTime>2020-10-01T09:55:50</ad:MovementDateTime>
               <ad:RetailSold>5.99</ad:RetailSold>
               <ad:WgtSold>6</ad:WgtSold>
               <ad:ItemNum>123456789</ad:ItemNum>
               <ad:UpcNum>00021234500000</ad:UpcNum>
               <ad:onPromotion>0</ad:onPromotion>
               <ad:labelSerialNum>0123456</ad:labelSerialNum>
            </ad:WSItemMovementInfo>
         </ad:movementArray>
      </ad:ImportItemMovement>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This policy returns:

```json
{
    "StoreNumber": 52,
    "BarcodeNumber": "00021234500000",

    "Type": "W",
    "QuantitySold": 6,


    "TotalRetail": 5.99,
    "PromotionType": 0,
    "SerialNumber": "0123456",
    "MovementDateTime": "10/1/2020 9:55:50 AM"
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will compare this to what I did and see where I get and let you know.  When I tried myself I kept getting could not deserialize in the Test tab in APIM but I couldn't figure out how to get more details about what the issue was.

Comment: Ok after some more messing around with what you provided we are REALLY close now.  <% for %> is what I think I need now as <ad:WSItemMovementInfo> can be repeated inside of the <ad:movementArray>  Now that I see what you did SOAP to REST in Azure APIM means the opposite of what I was expecting which is where a lot of confusion was.  Once I get the array part sorted out some I'll update my question to include your response and mark this as answered.

Comment: When it comes to arrays, maybe this helps:
https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/
`{% JSONArrayFor orderline in body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderLines %}
{% endJSONArrayFor %}`

Comment: After I change the Poilicy is there a way to see what the output of that policy is going to be so I know if it's right or not?

Comment: For completeness, I've updated what I have now so that anyone in the future that finds this will have something that works.  I will mark this as the answer but it was only what helped me get to the final answer.  I'm sure I'll have more questions on this in the future as we do others and for getting results back to the user as a SOAP response but I feel that you have gotten me 100% of the way with the initial question and I very much appreciate that.

Comment: For debugging reasons I've added the ` <trace source="inbound">@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(true))</trace>` policy. If you have a product attached to the API and by using an administration subscription key (which is default in the Test API tab) you can check each step performed by APIM in the _Traces_ window after request execution. Glad that you have it up and running now! I'm sure you'll find further support here if anything occurs :)